# Cannot invoke initialiser for type 'Checklist' with an argument list of type '(())'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

On the declaration of Checklist it shows an error.
Here its my code:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    lists = [Checklist]()

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    var name: String

    var list = Checklist(name = " Birthdays")
    lists.append(list)

    list = Checklist(name = "Groceries")
    lists.append(list)

    list = Checklist(name = "Cool Apps")
    lists.append(list)

    list = Checklist(name = "To Do")
    lists.append(list)


}
```

Comment: Take the tine to read the Swift documentation.

Comment: But how could I solve these problem?

Comment: By learning the Swift language. Yes, it takes time, is tedious and boring but that is a price that must be paid.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. Do you know any Tutorials of Swift Language

Comment: Apple has an iBook on the language: *The Swift Programmig Language*. Tutorials are narrowly focused and generally assume a reasonably good knowledge of the language. Also see the [Stanford online course](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-8-apps-swift/id961180099) via iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the other `init` method looks like:

```
required init(name theName: String)
{
     // theName is the parameter and String is the type
}
```

You should be doing something like this:

```
list = Checklist("To Do")
```